# What's a good Graph class to implement my logical game board?

Tags: java, swing, graph

I'm creating a board game on my computer using Java Swing.

Here's an image of the Swing GUI.  I realize that it's hard to read the text of the board squares in this image.  The requirement is that the player can move clockwise or counter-clockwise on the outside of the board, and through a stockholders meeting.

[image: Stock Market Game GUI]

When it came time to create a logical model of the game board, I ran into problems.

Here's an enlarged image of the lower left of the game board.

[image: Stock Market Game GUI 2]

The first logical model I tried was a List of my AbstractSquare class.

```
package com.ggl.stockmarket.game.model.board;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.TextLayout;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.ggl.stockmarket.game.model.GameStatus;
import com.ggl.stockmarket.game.view.StockMarketFont;

public abstract class AbstractSquare {

    public static final int IMAGE_WIDTH = 160;
    public static final int IMAGE_HEIGHT = 192;

    public static final Insets INSETS = new Insets(4, 2, 4, 2);

    /**
     * The key to the square in the bidirectional graph.
     */
    protected Integer graphKey;

    /**
     * The direction to move on the next turn. +1 means clockwise, -1 means
     * counter-clockwise, and zero means that an odd dice roll is clockwise, while
     * an even dice roll is counter-clockwise.
     */
    protected int direction;

    /**
     * The direction and distance to move the market. A positive integer means the
     * market moves down. A negative integer means the market moves up.
     */
    protected int marketAmount;

    /**
     * Pointer to the location in the List of the previous board square.
     */
    protected int previousPointer;

    /**
     * Pointer to the locatio0n in the List of the next board square.
     */
    protected int nextPointer;

    /**
     * The amount to multiply the stock. As an example; "1 for 1" multiplies the
     * stock by 2.
     */
    protected int stockMultiplier;

    protected Color backgroundColor;

    protected Dimension squareSize;

    protected Rectangle boardLocation;

    protected String multiplierText;

    public Integer getGraphKey() {
        return graphKey;
    }

    public void setGraphKey(Integer graphKey) {
        this.graphKey = graphKey;
    }

    /**
     * The direction to move on the next turn.
     * 
     * @param roll - The dice roll total.
     * @return +1 is clockwise and -1 is counter-clockwise.
     */
    public int getDirection(int roll) {
        if (direction == 0) {
            if ((roll / 2 * 2) == roll) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return +1;
            }
        } else {
            return direction;
        }
    }

    public void setDirection(int direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    public int getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    public int getMarketAmount() {
        return marketAmount;
    }

    public void setMarketAmount(int marketAmount) {
        this.marketAmount = marketAmount;
    }

    public Color getBackgroundColor() {
        return backgroundColor;
    }

    public void setBackgroundColor(Color backgroundColor) {
        this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    }

    public Rectangle getBoardLocation() {
        return boardLocation;
    }

    public void setBoardLocation(Rectangle boardLocation) {
        this.boardLocation = boardLocation;
    }

    public int getPreviousPointer() {
        return previousPointer;
    }

    public void setPreviousPointer(int previousPointer) {
        this.previousPointer = previousPointer;
    }

    public int getNextPointer() {
        return nextPointer;
    }

    public void setNextPointer(int nextPointer) {
        this.nextPointer = nextPointer;
    }

    public int getStockMultiplier() {
        return stockMultiplier;
    }

    public void setStockMultiplier(int stockMultiplier) {
        this.stockMultiplier = stockMultiplier;
    }

    public Dimension getSquareSize() {
        return squareSize;
    }

    public void setSquareSize(Dimension squareSize) {
        this.squareSize = squareSize;
    }

    public String getMultiplierText() {
        return multiplierText;
    }

    public void setMultiplierText(String multiplierText) {
        this.multiplierText = multiplierText;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((graphKey == null) ? 0 : graphKey.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        AbstractSquare other = (AbstractSquare) obj;
        if (graphKey == null) {
            if (other.graphKey != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!graphKey.equals(other.graphKey))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public List<String> splitStockName(String name) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        int pos = name.lastIndexOf(' ');
        if (pos < 0) {
            list.add(name);
        } else {
            list.add(name.substring(0, pos));
            list.add(name.substring(pos + 1));
        }
        return list;
    }

    public BufferedImage drawOutsideImage() {
        int width = squareSize.width;
        int height = squareSize.height;
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bufferedImage.getGraphics();
        drawOutsideSquare(g, width, height, INSETS);
        drawMovementText(g, width, height);
        drawMovementArrows(g, width, height);
        g.dispose();

        return bufferedImage;
    }

    protected BufferedImage drawOutsideImage(int width, int height, Insets insets) {
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bufferedImage.getGraphics();
        drawOutsideSquare(g, width, height, insets);
        drawMovementText(g, width, height);
        drawMovementArrows(g, width, height);

        return bufferedImage;
    }

    protected void drawOutsideSquare(Graphics2D g, int width, int height, Insets insets) {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        if (backgroundColor == null) {
            g.setColor(Color.white);
        } else {
            g.setColor(backgroundColor);
        }
        g.fillRect(insets.left, insets.top, width - insets.right - insets.left, height - insets.bottom - insets.top);
    }

    protected void drawMovementText(Graphics2D g, int width, int height) {
        Font directionFont = StockMarketFont.getBoldFont(16);
        FontRenderContext frc = g.getFontRenderContext();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (marketAmount < 0) {
            sb.append("Down ");
            sb.append(Math.abs(marketAmount));
        } else if (marketAmount > 0) {
            sb.append("Up ");
            sb.append(marketAmount);
        } else {
            sb.append("Odd    Even");
        }

        setTextColor(g);
        TextLayout layout = new TextLayout(sb.toString(), directionFont, frc);
        Rectangle2D bounds = layout.getBounds();
        float fx = (float) (bounds.getX()) + (float) (width - bounds.getWidth()) * 0.5F;
        float fy = (float) height - 10.0F;
        layout.draw(g, fx, fy);
    }

    public void setTextColor(Graphics2D g) {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        if ((backgroundColor != null) && (backgroundColor.equals(Color.blue))) {
            g.setColor(Color.white);
        }
    }

    protected void drawMovementArrows(Graphics2D g, int width, int height) {
        if (direction == 0) {
            int w = (width - 30) / 2;
            int x = 10;
            int y = height - 40;
            drawArrow(g, x, y, +1, w);
            x = width - w - 10;
            drawArrow(g, x, y, -1, w);
        } else {
            int w = (width - 40);
            int x = (width - w) / 2;
            int y = height - 40;
            drawArrow(g, x, y, direction, w);
        }
    }

    protected void drawArrow(Graphics2D g, int x, int y, int direction, int length) {
        // arrow thickness, arrow point height and width
        int t = 4;
        int h = 14;
        int w = 20;

        Polygon p = new Polygon();
        if (direction > 0) {
            g.fillRect(x + h, y, length - h, t);
            p.addPoint(x + h, y - ((w - t) / 2));
            p.addPoint(x + h, y + ((w + t) / 2));
            p.addPoint(x, y + (t / 2));
        } else {
            g.fillRect(x, y, length - h, t);
            p.addPoint(x + length - h, y - ((w - t) / 2));
            p.addPoint(x + length - h, y + ((w + t) / 2));
            p.addPoint(x + length, y + (t / 2));
        }
        g.fillPolygon(p);
    }

    public BufferedImage drawInsideImage(Insets insets) {
        int width = squareSize.width;
        int height = squareSize.height;
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bufferedImage.getGraphics();
        g.dispose();
        return bufferedImage;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(graphKey);
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public abstract void execute(GameStatus gameStatus);

}
```

For the moment, ignore the graphKey field.  The AbstractSquare class contains all the fields needed for all of the sqaures on the game board.  No square uses all of the fields.  Each sqaure uses the fields that are needed for the sqaure.

The problem is that the board cannot be represented by a simple graph.  As you can see on the enlarged game board, your move direction is determined by the arrow at the bottom of the square you start your turn on.  You can move from the start square in either direction, depending on whether the dice roll was odd or even.

When you land on a stocholders meeting square during your roll, you have the choice whether to continue moving on the outside of the board or move into the stockholders meeting, assuming you own at least one share of that stock.

After I decided a List of AbstractSquares wasn't going to work, I investigated directed graphs.  I found this code on [Geeks For Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementing-generic-graph-in-java/)

```
// Java program to implement Graph 
// with the help of Generics 

import java.util.*; 

class Graph<T> { 

    // We use Hashmap to store the edges in the graph 
    private Map<T, List<T> > map = new HashMap<>(); 

    // This function adds a new vertex to the graph 
    public void addVertex(T s) 
    { 
        map.put(s, new LinkedList<T>()); 
    } 

    // This function adds the edge 
    // between source to destination 
    public void addEdge(T source, 
                        T destination, 
                        boolean bidirectional) 
    { 

        if (!map.containsKey(source)) 
            addVertex(source); 

        if (!map.containsKey(destination)) 
            addVertex(destination); 

        map.get(source).add(destination); 
        if (bidirectional == true) { 
            map.get(destination).add(source); 
        } 
    } 

    // This function gives the count of vertices 
    public void getVertexCount() 
    { 
        System.out.println("The graph has "
                        + map.keySet().size() 
                        + " vertex"); 
    } 

    // This function gives the count of edges 
    public void getEdgesCount(boolean bidirection) 
    { 
        int count = 0; 
        for (T v : map.keySet()) { 
            count += map.get(v).size(); 
        } 
        if (bidirection == true) { 
            count = count / 2; 
        } 
        System.out.println("The graph has "
                        + count 
                        + " edges."); 
    } 

    // This function gives whether 
    // a vertex is present or not. 
    public void hasVertex(T s) 
    { 
        if (map.containsKey(s)) { 
            System.out.println("The graph contains "
                            + s + " as a vertex."); 
        } 
        else { 
            System.out.println("The graph does not contain "
                            + s + " as a vertex."); 
        } 
    } 

    // This function gives whether an edge is present or not. 
    public void hasEdge(T s, T d) 
    { 
        if (map.get(s).contains(d)) { 
            System.out.println("The graph has an edge between "
                            + s + " and " + d + "."); 
        } 
        else { 
            System.out.println("The graph has no edge between "
                            + s + " and " + d + "."); 
        } 
    } 

    // Prints the adjancency list of each vertex. 
    @Override
    public String toString() 
    { 
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 

        for (T v : map.keySet()) { 
            builder.append(v.toString() + ": "); 
            for (T w : map.get(v)) { 
                builder.append(w.toString() + " "); 
            } 
            builder.append("\n"); 
        } 

        return (builder.toString()); 
    } 
} 

// Driver Code 
public class Main { 

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 

        // Object of graph is created. 
        Graph<Integer> g = new Graph<Integer>(); 

        // edges are added. 
        // Since the graph is bidirectional, 
        // so boolean bidirectional is passed as true. 
        g.addEdge(0, 1, true); 
        g.addEdge(0, 4, true); 
        g.addEdge(1, 2, true); 
        g.addEdge(1, 3, true); 
        g.addEdge(1, 4, true); 
        g.addEdge(2, 3, true); 
        g.addEdge(3, 4, true); 

        // print the graph. 
        System.out.println("Graph:\n"
                        + g.toString()); 

        // gives the no of vertices in the graph. 
        g.getVertexCount(); 

        // gives the no of edges in the graph. 
        g.getEdgesCount(true); 

        // tells whether the edge is present or not. 
        g.hasEdge(3, 4); 

        // tells whether vertex is present or not 
        g.hasVertex(5); 
    } 
}
```

The problem with this code is that my AbstractSqare instances had no natural key that I could use to create the graph of the game board.

My question is, how can I use a graph to implement the logical model of my game board?

I need to determine the intermediate squares of a dice roll so I can animate the movement of the piece.  I also need to ask the player whether or not to enter a stockholders meeting, again assuming the player owns at least one share of the stock.

Comment: Wouldn't GitHub be a better location to publish this?

Answer (score 0):

After a week of trial and error, I came up with a modified version of the Graph class from Geeks For Geeks.

```
package com.ggl.stockmarket.game.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * This class creates a directed or a bidirectional graph.
 * 
 * @author Copied from the website GeeksForGeeks. Modified heavily by Gilbert Le
 *         Blanc
 * 
 * @param <T> - Class to be modeled as a graph..
 */
public class Graph<T> {

    // We use a List to store the objects
    private List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    // We use a Hashmap to store the key and edges in the graph
    private Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * This method adds the class object and returns an Integer
     * key to the class object.
     * @param e - The class object to add.
     * @return The Integer key to the class object.
     */
    public Integer add(T e) {
        list.add(e);
        return list.size() - 1;
    }

    /**
     * This method retrieves the Integer key for the class object.
     * 
     * @param e - The class object to test.
     * @return The Integer key to the class object, or -1 if the class object is not
     *         in the List.
     */
    public Integer getKey(T e) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            T g = list.get(i);
            if (g.equals(e)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public T get(int key) {
        return list.get(key);
    }

    public int size() {
        return list.size();
    }

    /**
     * This method adds the vertexes and edge between the Integer source and
     * destination keys.
     * 
     * @param source        - Source key.
     * @param destination   - Destination key.
     * @param bidirectional - True if the edge is bidirectio0nal, false if the edge
     *                      is in one direction.
     * 
     */
    public void addEdge(Integer source, Integer destination, boolean bidirectional) {
        if (!map.containsKey(source)) {
            addVertex(source);
        }
        if (!map.containsKey(destination)) {
            addVertex(destination);
        }
        map.get(source).add(destination);
        if (bidirectional == true) {
            map.get(destination).add(source);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method adds an Integer vertex to the graph.
     * 
     * @param s - Key to add as a vertex.
     */
    public void addVertex(Integer s) {
        map.put(s, new LinkedList<>());
    }

    // This function gives the count of vertices
    public String getVertexCount() {
        return "The graph has " + map.keySet().size() + " vertex";
    }

    // This function gives the count of edges
    public String getEdgesCount() {
        int count = 0;
        for (Integer v : map.keySet()) {
            count += map.get(v).size();
        }
        return "The graph has " + count + " edges.";
    }

    // This method returns the number of edges for a vertex
    public int getEdgeCount(Integer key) {
        return map.get(key).size();
    }

    // This method returns the edges for a vertex
    public List<Integer> getEdges(Integer key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    // This function gives whether a vertex is present or not.
    public String hasVertex(Integer s) {
        if (map.containsKey(s)) {
            return "The graph contains " + s + " as a vertex.";
        } else {
            return "The graph does not contain " + s + " as a vertex.";
        }
    }

    // This function gives whether an edge is present or not.
    public String hasEdge(Integer s, Integer d) {
        if (map.get(s).contains(d)) {
            return "The graph has an edge between " + s + " and " + d + ".";
        } else {
            return "The graph has no edge between " + s + " and " + d + ".";
        }
    }

    // Prints the adjacency list of each vertex.
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (Integer v : map.keySet()) {
            builder.append(v.toString() + ": ");
            for (Integer w : map.get(v)) {
                builder.append(w.toString() + " ");
            }
            builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        return (builder.toString());
    }

}
```

My inclination to store the AbstractSquare instances in an ArrayList turned out to be correct.  What I was missing was a good way to store the edges and vertexes of the graph.

I stored each AbstractSquare in an ArrayList.  As I added each AbstractSquare instace to the List, I saved the index of the instace as an edge.  I then created vertices to connect the edges.

Here's a display of the first 13 square edges and their vertices.  There are 120 logical squares on the board, so I'm not going to list all the vertices.  I had to add the stockholders meeting squares to the logical model twice.  Once to account for a clockwsie movement through the syockholders meeting and once to account for a counter-clockwise movement through the stockholders meeting.

```
0: 1 47 
1: 0 2 
2: 1 3 
3: 2 4 111 
4: 3 5 
5: 4 6 
6: 5 7 
7: 6 8 
8: 7 9 
9: 8 10 48 
10: 9 11 
11: 10 12 
12: 11 13
```

Square 0 can either move to square 47 or square 1.  There are 48 squares along the outside of the game board.  As you can see, a player in this part of the logical model can move in 2 or 3 directions.

Here's another part of the graph.  This is one of the 8 stockholders meeting graphs.

```
111: 112 
112: 113 
113: 114 
114: 115 
115: 116 
116: 117 
117: 118 
118: 119 
119: 45
```

Once inside a stockholders meeting, the player can only move in one direction.

Here's a little bit of code from the factory class that builds the logical model of the board.  The entire class is 862 lines.  You can see how I save the edges and create the vertices of the graph.

```
    // Position 0, starting at the bottom of the board,
    // going clockwise;
    StartSquare startSquare = createStartSquare();
    Integer originKey = board.add(startSquare);
    startSquare.setGraphKey(originKey);
    startSquareGraphKey[0] = originKey;

    BuySquare buySquare = createBuySquare(gameStatus, 3, +1, +1);
    Integer key2 = board.add(buySquare);
    board.addEdge(originKey, key2, true);
    buySquare.setGraphKey(key2);

    BuySquare buySquare2 = createBuySquare(gameStatus, 0, +1, -2);
    Integer key = board.add(buySquare2);
    board.addEdge(key2, key, true);
    buySquare2.setGraphKey(key);

    BuyLimitSquare buyLimitSquare = createBuyLimitSquare(gameStatus, 6, +1, +3, -1, 45);
    key2 = board.add(buyLimitSquare);
    board.addEdge(key, key2, true);
    buyLimitSquare.setGraphKey(key2);
    meetings[6] = buyLimitSquare;
```

Because I know I'm going to be asked, my logical model is separate from my view and my controller classes.  I have each square draw itself, and I have classes that take each square image and locate them on the board image.  I save the image rectangle of each square in the logical model, so I know where to draw the player pieces on the board image.

The point of this question and answer was to pass along my modified Graph class, in the hopes that it helps someone wrestling with a graph that's more complicated than the simple examples of graphs found in textbooks and online.